# React refs are not set up on tests if inside a react-bootstrap component

Tags: unit-testing, testing, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using:

- "react": "0.13.3"
- "react-bootstrap": "0.26.4"

Every time when I use a `ref` in a node inside a `<Modal />` or other [React Bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/) component, they are correctly setted when I run the system normally, but at test environment they just disappear.

I have tried all the render strategies of the react test utils, but seems to have no difference.

Comment: ref of a component?  ref of a DOM element?  What is your test environment?

Comment: No matter if it is a in a component of a simple DOM element. My test environment is karma + Jasmine, at any browser.